# Home made yeast cinnamon rolls deflating?

Tags: baking, yeast

I use an old time recipe that uses high-gluten flour, mashed potatoes flakes, sugar, salt, oil, yeast, eggs - I make them very often and lots of times have no issues.  However, lately I'm having issues with them falling after I get them out of the oven.  They come out looking wonderful, but as they sit they fall flat.  Any idea of what is happening?

More details:

I proof the yeast each time to be sure it's alive. I use active dry with 3 tbsp yeast + 1 tsp sugar in 105-115 degree water to proof it. I could have gotten sloppy as mentioned, being in a rush to get them done might have made me try to hurry things a bit too quickly. I will also try putting half the batch back in for 10 additional minutes to see if that cures the problem along with working the dough just a bit longer.

Comment: Some times when you get comfortable with a recipe, you start to deviate or get sloppy. Are you following the recipe as religiously as when you first learned the recipe?

Comment: Have you changed your brand of yeast? My "tried and true" recipe changed when I tried moving from one brand yeast to another. Conversely, I found that changing sugar from cane to beet had an opposite effect.

Comment: Is this a recipe that uses literally no gluten-containing flour, or did you just omit it from your description?

Comment: You definitely need to give us the rest of the details of the process I think.

Comment: How much dough are you making (or how much flour + potatoes do you use)?  How do you store your yeast?  You can reply in the comments or click "edit" under your question to add more information.

Answer (score 1):

Next time pop half of the batch back in the oven for an extra 10min and see if they too fall.
Getting the gluten to really set may be all that is needed.

If not, dough might be a bit weak -shorter strands of gluten with a lot of starch- and decreasing water or working the dough longer are the next possible experiments.

Answer (score 1):

When I see 3 tablespoons of yeast I think it sounds like a lot since it would make a lot of dough. in that case you are overproofing them. That will also cause them to deflate when taken out of the oven.